# Problems with Sencha Touch variable access

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm quite new to using Sencha Touch. I'm creating an app that has a sidebar and a map pane and when the user clicks on the Show Map button in the sidebar area the map is supposed to center on that location. Where I'm having an issue is that I'm unsure of how to access the {lat} and {lon} properties that are in the tpl variable from the handler function. My apologies if this is a trivial question, but it has me stumped.

```
Ext.define('Admin.view.Details',
{
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'details',

config:
{
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    scrollable: 'vertical',
    title: 'Individual',
    tpl:
    [
        'Account Number: {comid}',
        '<br />',
        'Address: ',
        '{address} <br />',
        '{lat},{lon}',
    ],

    items:
    [
        {
            title: 'Utilities',
            items:
            [
                {
                    xtype: 'selectfield',
                    label: 'Utility Type',
                    options: 
                    [
                        {text: 'Electricity', value: 'U1'},
                        {text: 'Water', value: 'U2'},
                        {text: 'Gas', value: 'u3' },
                    ],

                    id: 'utilityType',
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'selectfield',
                    label: 'Coverage Area',
                    options: 
                    [
                        {text: 'Subdivision', value: 'a1'},
                        {text: 'Zipcode', value: 'a2'},
                        {text: 'County', value: 'a3' },
                    ],

                    id: 'areaType',
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Show Map',
                    ui: 'round',
                    padding:3,
                    margin:10,
                    id:  'mapsBTN',
                    handler: function() {

                        olMap.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform
                        (
                            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                            olMap.getProjectionObject()
                        ), 16);

                    }
                },
            ]
        },
    ]
}
});
```

Comment: Are you using MVC paradigm ? If so then why do you use a handler ? You could add a reference to your button in the view's controller and listen to the itemtap event there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either implement de handler in your view's controller by adding references to your view and your button and then add a listener for the `itemtap` event of the button OR implement it in the constructor method of the view :

```
Ext.define('Admin.view.Details',{
  extend: 'Ext.Panel',
  xtype: 'details',

  config:{
    ...
  },

  constructor: function() {
    this.callParent(arguments);

    var me = this;

    this.child('#mapsBTN').setHandler(function() {
      me.getTpl(); // Here's your tpl config object
    });
  }
});
```

Hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

You can get any variable inside config object by getter.

```
this.getTpl(); //returns tpl variable
```

Also note that `this` must point out to your `Admin.view.Details` view.

Comment: In other word you need to add scope: this to you button's config otherwise this will point to the button and not the view.

Comment: After I added: `scope: this` and tried just to log the result of getTpl I received the following exception `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'getTpl'`